# Does $f_n \to 0$, a.e., implies $\int_{\mathbb R} \sin(f_n(x)) dx \to 0$, when each $f_n \in L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of $L^1(\mathbb R)$ functions converging a.e. to zero.
Does
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{\mathbb R} \sin(f_n(x)) dx = 0? 
$$

I think the answer is no, but I can't find a counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. For example, consider $f_n=\chi_{[n, n+1]}$.

Answer (score 4):

Try $f_n:=\frac{\pi}2\chi_{(n,n+1)}$.